# Install Windows 10 IoT Core from Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, windows-iot

I'm new to Raspberry Pi, I'm looking for some help. I need to install Windows 10 IoT core, I currently have Raspbian installed on my SD card. What can I do from NOOBS to install Win 10 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot to recovery with a working internet connection.

It should show in the list.
If you don't have a internet connection on instal it seems to hang as the win install bits try to authorize your Microsoft account for the install.

Comment: I tried this several times, holding the `Shift` key doesn't seem to do anything at all. It shows the rainbow screen, then a black terminal with loading details, then the standard Raspbian UI.

Comment: You don't need to hold it. holding it fires key repeat. So you are likely entering recovery then a swift exit. Just press it once when prompted, see if that gets you in.